# how to install modelsim SE 6.5b?

Tags: system-installation

I want to know how to install my version of modelsim SE 6.5b on ubuntu 14.04?
when i open the .linux file these error appeared "There is no application installed for “executable” files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?"

Answer (score 1):

> You need to install the package build-essential for making the package
>   and checkinstall for putting it into your package manager.

Open the Terminal and use this command line:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
```

<sub>[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)</sub>

Comment: what do you mean by package , i want to understand ?!!

Comment: and what is the second step ?!

Comment: next step run `/.linux` in terminal

Comment: sorry I am new user of unbuntu, how to run /.linux just type "/.linux"

Comment: Go to the path that you saved your .linux file there. for example you saved that in `/home/your_username/Documents/`. then run `cd /home/your_username/Documents/` and next run `/.linux` (in terminal use <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<T> to open)